# Base resistor too low problematic?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, current, bjt

I have recently designed and ordered some PCBs which can combine a horizontal and a vertical video sync signal into one composite sync signal (all are TTL signals). This is done using a BJT circuit which acts as an AND gate. I have received the PCBs today, but it turns out I made a mistake for one resistor value.
[image]

The base resistor R2 has to be 10k ohm, not 100 ohm. Will this be a problem for the functionality of the circuit? Because I prefer not to replace it when it is not necessary, since it is an 0402 SMD resistor.

Comment: It might not work, but it shouldn't break anything. You don't appear to have any termination on either of your inputs, though, which might also be a problem, regardless of the base resistor.

Comment: Oh, actually, yes, it definitely won't work. This won't act as an and gate unless R2 >> R4; as it is now, CSYNC1 will always be high whenever HSYNC1 is high. Though this is a pretty poor and gate in general. And it's definitely not ttl, so I'm going to remove that tag.